# Wrapping items vertically inside DataList when re-sizing browser

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a three column DataList and I'm trying to wrap the three items that appear from horizontally to vertically. I believe the problem which prevents this from happening is the three column DataList which should change to one column DataList.

At the moment I'm trying to wrap the 'boxer' divs verically but no success.

Any ideas how to achieve this?

```
<div class="dottedx">
     <div class="wrapping">
        <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server" DataKeyField="ProductID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" BorderColor="Black"
            CellPadding="5" CellSpacing="5" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="3" BorderWidth="0px" >
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div id="boxer" class="column">
                    <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# "~/images/topimages/" & Eval("Image") %>' cssclass="topimage" />
                    <br /><br />
                    ProductID:
                      <asp:Label ID="ProductIDLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ProductID") %>' />
                    <br />
                    Name:
                      <asp:Label ID="NameLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' />
                    <br />
                </div>
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:DataList>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using **float: left**?

Perhaps you can post a visual example?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by making the layout flow and removing the repeatcolumns=3. By float: left the items are sorted sideways.